# Why does Firefox 2 display fonts larger than specified in CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, font-size

I have a webpage where Firefox 2 displays the font certain, really specific elements, larger than than what I specified in the CSS.

When I look at the affected element (mostly `td` elements as far as I can tell) with Firebug, I see that the `font-size` is inherited from the `body` (11px, so its not a relative size). No styles overwrite this `font-size`, anywhere. When I toggle the *Show computed style* option, the `font-size` is displayed as 16px, Firefox's default.

It seems that the `td` does not inherit the `font-size` properly. Obviously, I could specify a more specific CSS selector targeting the `td` (which in fact works) but I can't find any documented behavior of Firefox not inheriting the `font-size` properly. It only happens in just a few tables, but completely unrelated to each other.

Does anyone know if I am overlooking something or is this a rendering issue in Firefox? Internet Explorer (I know, not the best reference for standards compliance) does not scale the font sizes up in tables.

Comment: This question is missing the question ;)

Comment: You're absolutely right ;) There's your question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a reasonably well known annoyance: TABLEs and TDs will inherit all font styles except font-size, at least in XHTML. To "fix" this, set the font size also for the TABLE or TD element.

So to clarify, this is not Firefox-specific. Did you test in other browsers?